# изменить/добавить запись в БД из другой модели

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Допустим, я нахожусь в `view Category`, но мне надо изменить запись в БД из другой модели, точнее в модели `Product`.

В `view Category` написал:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => false,]);
<?= $form->field($product, 'rating')->textarea([]) ?>
```

**Но!**

Как мне отредактировать запись в БД?

Comment: но обращение же будет к экшну контроллера, а в экшне можно к любой модели обратиться

Comment: можно на примере?

Answer (score -1):

Довольно сложные структуры приложений так написать у Вас не получится. Или если получится - то будет дурно пахнуть. Так вот если начинаете копать так глубоко, то советую посмотреть для начала в сторону того, что в моделях не должно быть валидации. Отдайте её в форму (yii\base\Model), так вы сможете делать самостоятельные формы, после чего уже оперировать данными в моделях и самими моделями. Далее смотрите в сторону сервисного слоя, дабы сделать код контроллеров максимально простым.